# Create kiosk app without device owner or root

Tags: android, kiosk-mode

I need create an app like SureLock and KioWare. I don't understand how to block some disallowed apps.
Can anyone help me to develop such app.

Answer (score -2):

A way to accomplish what you are trying to achieve would be by creating a launcher app. You can find more information [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/LauncherApps.html).